# How to add an extra false field in the Django REST framework serializer?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I am using django's inbuilt `User` model to create a registration api with Django REST framework (DRF). I want client to post a request like this

```
 {
    username:'user1',
    email:'email@email.com,
    password:'password123',
    confirm_password:'password123'
}
```

The trouble is In the django's built in 'User' database have no field as `confirm_password`. I dont want to add additional columns to the database and need this false field only to validate the two passwords and not to included it in the database. I wrote this model serializer

```
class RegSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id','username', 'email', 'password', 'confirm_password')
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True},'confirm_password': {'write_only': True}}
```

and created user through

```
User.objects.create_user(request.data['username'], request.data['email'], request.data['password'])
```

But it shows this error

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Field name `confirm_password` is not valid for model `User`.

How do we add an extra false field in the Django REST framework serilizer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a new field to the serializer class as,

```
class RegSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    confirm_password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'email', 'password', 'confirm_password')
        extra_kwargs = {
            'password': {'write_only': True}
        }
```